# Is there a builtin method in Java to turn string into an array of integers?

Tags: java, arrays, integer, transform

I need to turn string into an array of integers. Each array slot would contain one letter in integer value. For example, string `omg` would be returned as something like

```
array[0] = 13; array[1] = 44; array[3] = 26;
```

EDIT These values of letters are thought up. I just want to know if there is a method to turn letters to integers.

Is there any builtin method for this?

Comment: `String.getBytes()`

Comment: How does o-->13, m-->44 and g-->26?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a varieties of ways of doing this, depending on exactly what you mean by "turn letters to integers".

- You can use `String.getBytes()` to encode the string into the system's default encoding and give you that as a `byte[]`.  The `byte` type is an integer type.
- You can use `String.toCharArray()` to give you the string's characters.  The `char` type is an integer type.
- You could do various other "mystery" transformations on the string; e.g. apply Caeser's cipher to each string character to give you a letter that you then turn into a number.

And you could then write a loop to turn a `char[]` or `byte[]` into an `int[]`, but there is no built-in method to do this step of the transformation ... if that's what you need.

Note that the first two approaches may give you different integers, depending on the string value and the system's default character encoding.  It is important that you understand what you are trying to do with this conversion ...

---

(I'm assuming that the example transformation in the Question should not be taken literally ...)

Answer (score 2):

Well for turning it into an array, try `char[] chars = str.toCharArray();`, and for converting it into an integer, use a for loop, and call varible.getNumericValue();. So an example would be:

```
String omg = "OMG";
char[] chars = omg.toCharArray();
int[] result;
for(char currentChar : chars){
    result[result.length] = currentChar.getNumericValue();//result.length starts at 1 more than the final index
}
```

Edit: Or just use String.getBytes as mentioned above.

Edit 2: Actually, this is completely wrong.

Comment: I don't think you want to use a foreach loop when writing values to array indices. Also you don't want to use result.length for the index value even if you were. And the string variable is called omg, not str...

Comment: I know, I realized how many things were wrong with it, and completely gave up.